# How can I check the current orientation of my windows phone device?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I need to know when the player is switching the orientation of the device. Therefore, I use this event, but I always this error message. What is wrong?

> this.OrientationChanged += OrientationChanged();
>
> No overload for method 'OrientationChanged' takes 0 arguments

How can I use this event in a MonoGame Windows Phone 8 game?

I use the following code in Game1.cs:

```
this.OrientationChanged += OrientationChanged();

void OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
    {

    }
}
```

My project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qa1ty2ydo1hqfwn/MonogameFarseerDemo.rar

Answer (score 0):

change the following line:

```
this.OrientationChanged += OrientationChanged();
```

with this:

```
this.OrientationChanged += OnOrientationChanged;

void OnOrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I changed it but now I get this error message:Cannot assign to 'OrientationChanged' because it is a 'method group'

Comment: please check again, the problem is OrientationChanged name is both used for event and the handler method.

Comment: It's not working. Now I get this error message: 'MonogameFarseerDemo.Game1' does not contain a definition for 'OrientationChanged' and no extension method 'OrientationChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'MonogameFarseerDemo.Game1' could be found

Comment: The `OrientationChanged` event is on `GameWindow`, not `Game`.  Use `this.Window.OrientationChanged += OnOrientationChanged;`

Comment: @Cole Campbell I changed it but now I get this error message: No overload for 'OnOrientationChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs>'

Comment: My advice is that you spend some time learning [how events work in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx).